# Difficulty with $.ajax "then()" function in typescript, after updating definition file

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 5.2`, and `Typescript` - along with definition files from `DefinitelyTyped`. You can see the latest release of this here:

### [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery)

I have a simple part of javascript that reads like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/service/model",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: raven.identity({ id: "model/default/testing" })
}).then((data) => {
    viewModel.set("Assortment", data);
    console.log("retrieved", data);
}).then(() => { .. more stuff happens .. }).done();
```

There is actually code in the `done` section, but it isn't giving any errors, so I've omitted it for now.

I do not know the version I had, but it was more than 12 days ago that I downloaded it. I'm trying to find out but having no luck - in either case, today, when I ran `NuGet` and saw there were some updates to various definition files, I went ahead and downloaded them.

And that is when everything fell apart. I now get this error message on that `then` chain.

> Supplied parameters do not match signature of call target

I can confirm that rolling back my `jquery.d.ts` file to the previous one resolves this. But I have no idea why. I honestly don't like sticking with outdated definitions because it'll just bite me far worse 3 or 4 releases down the line when I *need* to update it.

But I cannot figure out what changed to make this error occur.

You can see the `jquery.d.ts` that works **successfully** for me here:

### [Last Known Working Definition](https://gist.github.com/ciel/c73dae1aebd43b426ec0)

And the one that is **not working** here:

### [Failing Definition](https://gist.github.com/ciel/a48b9d8e7bb3baf684a8)

## Update

I forgot this at first. The differences in the file as it pertains to that function are shown here;

## Working

```
/**
 * Interface for the JQuery promise, part of callbacks
 */
interface JQueryPromise<T> {
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected.
     * 
     * @param alwaysCallbacks1 A function, or array of functions, that is called when the Deferred is resolved or rejected.
     * @param alwaysCallbacks2 Optional additional functions, or arrays of functions, that are called when the Deferred is resolved or rejected.
     */
    always(alwaysCallbacks1?: JQueryPromiseCallback<T>, ...alwaysCallbacks2: JQueryPromiseCallback<T>[]): JQueryDeferred<T>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved.
     * 
     * @param doneCallbacks1 A function, or array of functions, that are called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param doneCallbacks2 Optional additional functions, or arrays of functions, that are called when the Deferred is resolved.
     */
    done(doneCallbacks1?: JQueryPromiseCallback<T>, ...doneCallbacks2: JQueryPromiseCallback<T>[]): JQueryDeferred<T>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is rejected.
     * 
     * @param failCallbacks1 A function, or array of functions, that are called when the Deferred is rejected.
     * @param failCallbacks2 Optional additional functions, or arrays of functions, that are called when the Deferred is rejected.
     */
    fail(failCallbacks1?: JQueryPromiseCallback<T>, ...failCallbacks2: JQueryPromiseCallback<T>[]): JQueryDeferred<T>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object generates progress notifications.
     * 
     * @param progressCallbacks A function, or array of functions, to be called when the Deferred generates progress notifications.
     */
    progress(...progressCallbacks: JQueryPromiseCallback<T>[]): JQueryDeferred<T>;

    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected.
     * 
     * @param alwaysCallbacks A function, or array of functions, that is called when the Deferred is resolved or rejected.
     */
    always(...alwaysCallbacks: any[]): JQueryPromise<T>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved.
     * 
     * @param doneCallbacks A function, or array of functions, that are called when the Deferred is resolved.
     */
    done(...doneCallbacks: any[]): JQueryPromise<T>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is rejected.
     * 
     * @param failCallbacks A function, or array of functions, that are called when the Deferred is rejected.
     */
    fail(...failCallbacks: any[]): JQueryPromise<T>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object generates progress notifications.
     * 
     * @param progressCallbacks A function, or array of functions, to be called when the Deferred generates progress notifications.
     */
    progress(...progressCallbacks: any[]): JQueryPromise<T>;

    // Deprecated - given no typings
    pipe(doneFilter?: (x: any) => any, failFilter?: (x: any) => any, progressFilter?: (x: any) => any): JQueryPromise<any>;

    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     * @param progressFilter An optional function that is called when progress notifications are sent to the Deferred.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (value: T) => U, failFilter?: (...reasons: any[]) => U, progressFilter?: (...progression: any[]) => any): JQueryPromise<U>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     * @param progressFilter An optional function that is called when progress notifications are sent to the Deferred.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (value: T) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, failFilter?: (...reasons: any[]) => U, progressFilter?: (...progression: any[]) => any): JQueryPromise<U>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     * @param progressFilter An optional function that is called when progress notifications are sent to the Deferred.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (value: T) => U, failFilter?: (...reasons: any[]) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, progressFilter?: (...progression: any[]) => any): JQueryPromise<U>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     * @param progressFilter An optional function that is called when progress notifications are sent to the Deferred.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (value: T) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, failFilter?: (...reasons: any[]) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, progressFilter?: (...progression: any[]) => any): JQueryPromise<U>;

    // Because JQuery Promises Suck
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     * @param progressFilter An optional function that is called when progress notifications are sent to the Deferred.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (...values: any[]) => U, failFilter?: (...reasons: any[]) => U, progressFilter?: (...progression: any[]) => any): JQueryPromise<U>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     * @param progressFilter An optional function that is called when progress notifications are sent to the Deferred.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (...values: any[]) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, failFilter?: (...reasons: any[]) => U, progressFilter?: (...progression: any[]) => any): JQueryPromise<U>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     * @param progressFilter An optional function that is called when progress notifications are sent to the Deferred.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (...values: any[]) => U, failFilter?: (...reasons: any[]) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, progressFilter?: (...progression: any[]) => any): JQueryPromise<U>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     * @param progressFilter An optional function that is called when progress notifications are sent to the Deferred.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (...values: any[]) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, failFilter?: (...reasons: any[]) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, progressFilter?: (...progression: any[]) => any): JQueryPromise<U>;
}
```

## Failing

```
/**
 * Allows jQuery Promises to interop with non-jQuery promises
 */
interface JQueryGenericPromise<T> {
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (value: T) => U, failFilter?: (reason: any) => U): JQueryGenericPromise<U>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (value: T) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, failFilter?: (reason: any) => U): JQueryGenericPromise<U>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (value: T) => U, failFilter?: (reason: any) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>): JQueryGenericPromise<U>;
    /**
     * Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.
     * 
     * @param doneFilter A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
     * @param failFilter An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.
     */
    then<U>(doneFilter: (value: T) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>, failFilter?: (reason: any) => JQueryGenericPromise<U>): JQueryGenericPromise<U>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diffing the two it seems to be this PR : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/2348/files

Would appreciate an issue report : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues?state=open mentioning the test that fails + PR.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do unit tests in Javascript yet, so I have no idea what test fails.

Comment: These aren't *javascript* tests, These are more like does it compile test . More information here : http://definitelytyped.org/guides/contributing.html

Comment: Hey, thanks. I am still a bit uncertain, but I will give it a try. Is it considered acceptable practice to link to this SO topic as well, to ensure that it gets read properly even if I do it wrong?

Comment: So I would state that the PR in my issue statement, and explain what isn't functioning?

Comment: And to be absolutely certain I get what is going on, by `PR` you mean a _"pull request"_, right? Can I bother you to know __how__ you discerned that it was that pull request? I'm still new to github, so this is kind of mystical to me.

Comment: Hurrah! I just did my very first pull request, and it worked! Thank you so much for your help.